# PDF reader for Java as PDF.js

Tags: java, pdf, pdf.js, pdfparser

We have a project where we use `pdf.js` to render a PDF into webpage and it creates HTML container elements for the PDF pages. The content of the PDF is split as HTML `span` in the view.

Attached is the image which shows how pdf text is rendered in the view. It also shows, each `span` has a `data-key` does not corresponds to a line in PDF.

[image]

Now, I need a pdf reader for java which reads and breaks the content as `span` with `data-key` or just the `span` in the order.

There are lot of java libraries available to read PDF content which gets the content line by line but that does not solve my issue. I need a java library which could break the content equivalent to `span` in the view.

Comment: Why do you need this to be java? Can't you just group all the spans with the same value of the `top` css style attribute?

Comment: We work pdf in the frontend and store some data. Later we do some analysis on these pdf's in the backend using java 8 so we need to read the content of the pdf in java. If you can see, the `span` has `data-key` and I need that for analysis.

Comment: Are your PDFs marked? Or arbitrary?

Comment: Am not sure what marked or arbitrary pdf mean but the pdf is final and it cannot be edited. if that answers your question.